# valid char array (is this a valid string)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I am filling a char array using ReadProcessMemory and I am curious to know what is the 'correct/standard/best' way to determine if the returned char array contains a valid string.  I'm not worried about the string, it can contain the a-zA-Z0-9 plus spaces and characters such as './_' and a few other things but really all I want to know if it is valid and just not full of junk.

```
int char_read_length = 255;
char data[255];
memset(data, 0, char_read_length);
ReadProcessMemory( hProcess, (void *)start, data, char_read_length, &lpRead);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Consider editing your question to define what makes the string "valid" or "junk". Those terms are highly subjective...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be treated as a string if it contains a NUL character to terminate the string.  If there is no NUL, treating it as a string will run off the end of the buffer and cause very bad things to happen.  Thus:

```
bool is_it_a_string = memchr(data, 0, char_read_length);
```

Comment: If "string" in this case means "null terminated string", then this is true. +1.

Comment: That's the kind of string you keep in a char array.  The question "does this char array contain a valid string?" makes no sense for other values of string, such as `std::string` (needs other members such as length) or `BSTR` (needs to be array of `wchar_t`, plus have a length prefix).

Comment: Thank you Ben, this is what I was after.

Comment: On the other hand, even strings which are not null terminated are still strings... i.e. strings of bytes.

Comment: The strings are null  terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things here:

1. We do not know what you mean by "valid". If you want a string that contains only those characters, write yourself a loop that checks each character to see if it is one of those characters.
2. There's no need to call memset on your array, because ReadProcessMemory is going to write to that buffer for you anyway.
3. Where is `lpRead` defined? If it really is a `lp` variable (which stands for "long pointer"), you should **not** be taking it's address before passing it to ReadProcessMemory. If it is not a pointer then you should change it's name so that it doesn't start with LP. (Actually, you might want to not use Hungarian notation anyway but if you're going to use it at least do it correctly)
4. If this is C++, you should be using `static_cast` rather than the C style cast to cast the character pointer to a void pointer.

Comment: By valid I mean 'it is a string.'  I can pass it with boost regex but I was simply wondering if there is a function which I haven't found in the c++ libraries which would do that anyway.  There is a function called isalnum() but this doesn't take into account characters such as './_ ' etc.  The notation is straight out of Hoglund and so is the way that I am using ReadProcessMemory.

Comment: @flavour404: Even a string of complete garbage is still a string. I don't know what "Hoglund" is. Yes, isalnum doesn't take into account things like . and /, etc. But you can write a function that does exactly what you want. Check if the character is a character in the range you wish or not.

Comment: wrt 4, there should be no cast at all

Comment: @Ben: A cast is required in C++. If it is C code, no cast is required. (`ReadProcessMemory` takes a `void *`)

Comment: @Billy: Conversion of any pointer type to `void*` is implicit in both C and C++.  No cast is needed.  No cast should be used.

Comment: @Ben: oops -- I'm thinking of conversions *from* void not conversions *to* void.

Comment: OTOH if `start` is some integral type and not a pointer, then a `reinterpret_cast` is needed.

Comment: @Ben: If `start` is some integral type, the OP is asking for pain in any case, eh?

Comment: @Billy: Not necessarily.  After all, he's reading memory from another process and needed some way to transfer the pointer across the process boundary.  Most ways (datagrams, LPARAM of a window message, etc) will require storing the pointer in an appropriately-sized integer.  And that's a good thing, because a pointer in one process does not have meaning as a pointer in another.

Comment: @Billy: Greg Hoglund and James Butler write books on security topics, they mainly focus on low level windows kernel exploits and secure software development.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably just use something like the following (note that using this would require ensuring that `data` is properly  `'\0'` terminated):

```
char const validChars[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                          "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                          "0123456789"
                          "./_"
                          " ";  // add whatever other characters are considered valid


bool isValidString(char const* s) 
{
    return strspn(s, validChars) == strlen(s);
}
```

If you want to check that the entire 255 bytes is 'valid', then you'd need to check that `strlen(data) == 255`, too.

There's probably a nice C++ STL algorithm that can handle this just as well, but I'd probably still just use `strspn()` due to a certain form of laziness.

Note that you probably need to check for an error return from `ReadProcessMemory()`.

Comment: Thank you, I am checking the return from ReadProcessMemory.